# How to get callback from activity back to fragment using interface

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, interface, onactivityresult

I have a fragment, where I have a button to choose an image from a gallery. The gallery is open successfully, but when I choose the image, I do not get the result from activity. So I consider to use a callback (interface). However, I do know how.

Could you suggest me something please?

**interface**

```
public interface CallbackListener {
    void onPhotoTake(String url);
}
```

**in fragment click**

```
@OnClick(R.id.addPhoto) void photo() {
        if (isStoragePermissionGranted()) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            context.startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
}
```

**activity**

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

- here I would like to send result **back to fragment** using interface

Comment: Hi, could you post some code to give us more information about it is implemented?

Comment: I editted my question and added some code

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to send data back to fragment class there can be a number of ways to do that:

**First**

1. Create a **public method in fragment class**
2. Call that method using the **fragment object** in activity class's `onActivityResult()`

---

**Second**

1. Create an interface in activity and implement that interface in fragment. Then with the help of interface, send your data to fragment
   e.g.

Activity class

```
DataReceivedListener listener;

public void setDataReceivedListener(DataReceivedListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

public interface DataReceivedListener {
    void onReceived(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
}
```

Fragment Class

```
class fragment extends Fragments implements yourActivityClassName.DataReceivedListener {
    @Override
    void onReceived(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    }

    onViewCreated(...) {
        ((yourActivityName) getActivity()).setDataReceivedListener(this);
    }
}
```

in Acitivity class

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (listener != null) {
        listener.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```