# Best way to pass one data to multiple fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a scenario that i have one activity and 4 fragment , from one of the fragment i am passing the data using interface to the main activity , I am receiving the value or say object , now what i need to do , i have to pass the same object to all other fragment . but i don't wanna to use bundle or static method/field , I just want to know the best idea or approach  to this question , what i can do ?

One solution i am thinking using the abstract class , Let's say my abstract class name is ParentFragmentAbstarct should implements the Fragment class and define a abstract method inside it let say setData(), then every Fragment should extends this Fragment class then abstract method is overridden in every fragment , now i am lost , how to set the value in it if i am getting the value only from one of the fragment(let's say from network response i am receiving the data in Fragment 2 n now how to set this same value in other three fragment)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40238172/2299040

Comment: @SahilManchanda i made a interface and when i am receiving the result in fragment , i pass the result on interface and recive the result on activity , but i need this result on other three fragment , i can use static field to hold object and pass to other Fragment or using bundle but i need other solution

Comment: How are you creating and maintaining those fragments. show that code

Comment: @SahilManchanda  This is the interview question , just need idea .

Comment: Please have a look at my answer

Comment: use `SharedPreferences`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Using Abstract Class with an Array of Fragment Object:

Like ViewPager you have an Adapter holding the instances of those fragments. When one of your fragments informs the MainActivity about the new data using  **Interface** then you can simple iterate on ViewPagerAdapter and call your abstract Method. All the fragments will get notified.

> Using Broadcast Receiver

You can declare your own broadcast receiver and made your fragments to listen to those broadcast. when the data is ready, your fragment can send a broadcast and all the other Fragments who are listening to this specific broadcast can thereafter update their state. Check this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23347872/2299040)

> Using Observable RxJava
>
> In ReactiveX an observer subscribes to an Observable. Then that
>   observer reacts to whatever item or sequence of items the Observable
>   emits. This pattern facilitates concurrent operations because it does
>   not need to block while waiting for the Observable to emit objects,
>   but instead it creates a sentry in the form of an observer that stands
>   ready to react appropriately at whatever future time the Observable
>   does so.

have a look at [observable](http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html)

> > Using EventBus
>
> EventBus is a publish/subscribe event bus for Android and Java.

This is a great [library](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus), very small footprint and gets the job done with ease

Answer (score 0):

You could create a singleton data manager class, and have all the fragments subscribe to it and listen for data changes. Each fragment can then have it's own implementation when recieving a state change.

Make any database calls in this manager class and distribute data to the listeners on response callbacks